# How to handle network interrupts and connection pooling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jdbc

I'm facing a problem in JavaEE(Glassfish and also TomEE) with connection pooling. When the network/datatier is down and going up again, the JDBC pool seems to "hang". So there are always timeouts while trying to get a connection to the datatier. I'm sure there is something to handle this behaviour. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What's your database ?

Comment: Postgres. But also MS-SQL with jdts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should configure the pool.

here the links: http://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html and http://tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html

Take care of XXXevictionXXX, validationquery and testXXX properties